# Why read() on file descriptor fails if lseek() is used?

Tags: c, file-io, io, posix

In the following example we close default `stderr` and reopen it on the temporary file via `fdopen()`, using descriptor `2`, which was `dup()`'ed from the temporary file descriptor. Then we `write()` directly to this descriptor `2`. We can safely do this, because the is the first write operation on file and thus it has the empty buffer. After this, we `fprintf()` to the new `stderr`. Then we close `stderr` (thus, its associated descriptor `2` is automatically closed). Original descriptor `fd` remains valid. Through it we go to the beginning of the temporary file, read its contents and print them to stdout. But the output is garbled:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
  int fd;
  char buf[200];
  int n;
  char fname[] = "/tmp/tst-perror.XXXXXX";
  fd = mkstemp (fname);
  fclose (stderr);
  dup2 (fd, 2);
  stderr = fdopen (2, "w");
  fd = fileno(stderr);
  char *s = "this is a test\n";
  n = write(fd, s, strlen(s));
  fprintf(stderr, "multibyte string\n");
  fclose (stderr);
//  close(fd);
//  fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
  lseek (fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  n = read (fd, buf, sizeof (buf));
  printf("%.*s", (int) n, buf);
  close (fd);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./a.out
����
```

If we uncomment the "close" and "open" lines and comment "lseek" line, the output is as expected:

```
$ ./a.out
this is a test
multibyte string
```

`write()` does not have a buffer, and `stderr` is written-off when it is closed, so
why the output is garbled if we do not close the file before reading it?

Comment: Also, be careful which stream you `lseek` on. See the NOTE in `man 2 lseek`, *"Some devices are incapable of seeking and POSIX does not specify which devices must support lseek()."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no check on return values from the functions. If it had been there you would have found the error.

Anyway, the issue is:

```
  fd = fileno(stderr);     // getting the fd from current stderr
  fclose (stderr);         // closing stderr
  ...
  lseek (fd, 0, SEEK_SET); // seeking on fd which was already closed
```

In the last call and subsequent calls `fd` is actually undefined (or rather it references closed file descriptor). Therefore any operation on `fd` will fail `EBADF` (not valid file descriptor).

Obviously if you include the `fd = open(...)` again, `fd` will become valid and the code will work.

Comment: Indeed, my real intent was to use "fd2" in "fileno" and "write" lines. Now everything works.